# How can I avoid specifying the cancel_url and the return_url in the merchant_preferences for PayPal?

Tags: redirect, paypal, documentation

How can I avoid specifying the `cancel_url` and the `return_url` in the merchant_preferences for PayPal?

I am trying to create a billing agreement token using the [v1/billing-agreements/agreement-tokens](https://developer.paypal.com/api/limited-release/reference-transactions/v1/#agreement-tokens-post-request-body) endpoint. One of the request fields for that is the `plan` field.

[image]

The `plan` itself is an object which has the not required `merchant_preferences` field.

[image]

But in reality trying to send the request without the `merchant_preferences` gives me the error:

```
{
    "name": "VALIDATION_ERROR",
    "debug_id": "[MY_DEBUG_ID]",
    "message": "Invalid request - see details",
    "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR",
    "details": [
        {
            "name": "shippingAddrMismatch",
            "message": "Shipping address combination invalid."
        },
        {
            "name": "plan/merchantPreferences",
            "message": "may not be null"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, I need to send that `merchant_preferences` object.

But if we check this `merchant_preferences` object, we will see that it requires the `cancel_url` and the `return_url`.

[image]

Now, my problem is that I do not want to provide any urls there, since my approach is the PayPal pop up, not a redirect. So, I dont have any redirects in the PayPal installments flow. How can I avoid providing those redirect urls?

I tried just not sending them and got this error:

```
{
    "name": "VALIDATION_ERROR",
    "debug_id": "[MY_DEBUG_ID]",
    "message": "Invalid request - see details",
    "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR",
    "details": [
        {
            "name": "plan/merchantPreferences/returnUrl",
            "message": "Invalid Url .Url should be of type <protocol>://<hostname>. eg. http://www.paypal.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "plan/merchantPreferences/cancelUrl",
            "message": "Invalid Url .Url should be of type <protocol>://<hostname>. eg. http://www.paypal.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

[Here](https://developer.paypal.com/api/limited-release/reference-transactions/v1) is the link to all that documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not avoid it. Provide *a* url.

Comment: But then I have to handle the request to those endpoints and support them, even though they are not going to be used. It just feels utterly wrong.

Comment: No, you do not.

Comment: So far I just put the `http://www.paypal.com` into those urls. Hope it will be okay.